# Java get first and last 2 byte from int var

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I want convert an int into 2 bytes representing that int.

Probably must use bitwise and bit shifting, but I dont know what to do.

```
int x; /* val to convert */


// ?????????


int b12; /* the first 2 bytes */
int b34; /* the last  2 bytes */
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// Shift 16 bits to the right.
int b12 = x >>> 16;

// Zeroes the upper 16 bits.
int b34 = x & 0xffff;
```

Comment: One should probably (depending on application) use an logical shift instead of an arithmetic one there. Also, the masking is redundant in the first case (all of the masked-out zeroes get shifted away anyway).

Comment: (This didn't make sense, because I stupidly edited my comment to say something completely different. It used to quip something about big-endian and little-endian interpretations of "first 2 bytes". Sorry for the confusion).

Comment: @Henning Thanks. I changed `>>` to `>>>`

Answer (score 0):

```
int b12 = (x & 0xFFFF);
int b34 = (x >>> 16);
```

Comment: x >> 16 won't work, that's a signed operation. Use >>> instead.